# Android:OnClick not working properly

Tags: android

In my app i have a popup menu, when i click the menuitem it collects the gps location , the problem is when i double tap the menu its triggering two times but i am peforming only onclick
not sure where i am doing wrong

```
LinearLayout popupmain = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.popupmain);
        ImageView popupImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
        TextView popupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.popupname);

        popupImage.setImageResource(popUpMenu.getImageResource());
        popupName.setText(popUpMenu.getMenuName());
        popupName.setTag(popUpMenu);
        popupmain.setTag(popUpMenu);
        popupName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doAction(v, activity);

            }
        });

        popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doAction(v, activity);

            }
        }); 


        return view;
    }

    public void doAction(View v, Activity activity) {

            Context myContext = v.getContext();
            PopUpMenu popUpMenu = (PopUpMenu) v.getTag();
            String result = popUpMenu.getMenuName();
            if (result != null
                    && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.savecurrentlocation))) {
                getLocation();  
        }
        private void getLocation() {
                manager = (LocationManager) parentActivity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                listener = new ManageLocation();
                listener.setSucessCallBack(this, "setLocation");
                listener.setFailureCallBack(this, "setNoLocation");
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        new Utils().getCurrentPlaceLocationProvider(manager), 0, 0,
                        listener);

            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

my popupmain xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popupmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/popupimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popupname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/default_date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your xml in your question pls

Comment: Not sure why you have two `onClickListeners` performing the same task where just one on `popupmain` should be enough, but to each his own I suppose. Anyway, why not use a boolean flag and check if a task is running by setting it _true_ at the start of `public void doAction()` and setting it to false at the end of `private void getLocation()`? And check the status of the flag in the `OnClickListener's` before calling `doAction(v, activity);`. I think this should do it.

Comment: can u explaain little bit more with code

Comment: @teekib: You asking me fella?

Comment: yes Siddharth Lele..can u pls explain more

Comment: @teekib: Sure. Give me a minute or two for the code.

Comment: @teekib: I have added the code. Do check it. Please don't use it as is. I typed it out in _notepad_ and it may have errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple v.setEnabled(false); solved my problem

```
 popupName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                     popupName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                v.setEnabled(false);
                performAction(v, activity);

            }
        }); 

        popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                v.setEnabled(false);
                performAction(v, activity);

            }
        }); 
                    performAction(v, activity);

                }
            }); 

            popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    v.setEnabled(false);
                    performAction(v, activity);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that popName and popImage is on the popMain in your activity or fragment XML .

If they are on this layout, it is quite normal behavior.

Because Layout route events its child after handling it.

delete  this piece of code

```
   popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doAction(v, activity);

            }
        });
```

Or add control logic like this(I dont know your main idea)

```
   popupName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(popupMainOpened)
                doAction(v, activity);

            }
        });

        popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            if(!popupMainOpened)
                doAction(v, activity);

            }
        });
```

or implement your LinearLayout by extending it LinearLayout and override  onTouchEvent
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: posted my layout..yes both are in same layout..how to avoid this?

Comment: @teekib Edited my answer. If I were you I prefer to extend My LinearLayout because of clean code.

Comment: what is popupMainOpened here??

Comment: @teekib popupMainOpened is flag which can be defined by you to prevent  DoAction to be handled twice. I just want to show a way how to accomplish this and I think it is unnecessary that the layout handle the OnClick event It cause this problem.

Comment: Firstly, do you understand your mistake? Layout handles all click event before its children handle. So this behaviour quite normal. But I want to handle both of them you can use flag logic. This piece of code doesnt run because flag is not changed. I dont know what you want to do so I dont change the flag... 
You cannot learn any platform by copying pasting all of answers and it doesnt always run. You should understand why I get this behaviour and how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your 'popUpMenu' instance as private class member and check whether it is already being displayed before calling 'doAction()'

Comment: Sorry i did not get you, can u please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, this is untested code. I just typed it out in notepad. I am not sure if it will work in *as is form* but should help you understand the logic behind it. And of course, the formatting is a little off. Adapt where necessary.

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

boolean runningAction = false;  // DECLARE AS A GLOBAL INSTANCE

    // IN YOUR GETVIEW()

    LinearLayout popupmain = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.popupmain);
    ImageView popupImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
    TextView popupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.popupname);

    popupImage.setImageResource(popUpMenu.getImageResource());
    popupName.setText(popUpMenu.getMenuName());

    // I AM SKIPPING THE REST

    popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (runningAction == false) {
            doAction(v, activity);
        } else {
                // DO NOTHING OR SHOW A TOAST THAT A FUNCTION IS IN PROGRESS
        }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

    // THE doAction()
    public void doAction(View v, Activity activity) {

        // TOGGLE THE boolean flag runningAction
        runningAction = true;

        Context myContext = v.getContext();
        PopUpMenu popUpMenu = (PopUpMenu) v.getTag();
        String result = popUpMenu.getMenuName();
        if (result != null
                    && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.savecurrentlocation))) {
            getLocation();  
        }

    // THE getLocation()
    private void getLocation() {
        manager = (LocationManager) parentActivity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new ManageLocation();
        listener.setSucessCallBack(this, "setLocation");
        listener.setFailureCallBack(this, "setNoLocation");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        new Utils().getCurrentPlaceLocationProvider(manager), 0, 0,
                        listener);

        // TOGGLE THE boolean flag runningAction TO PREPARE FOR NEXT LOCATION UPDATE
        runningAction = false;

     }
}
```

Also, note that I have only set the ClickListener to the `popupmain LinearLayout` and not the `popupName TextView`

Comment: i implemented your code but still facing same problem ..the layout is opening two times

Comment: @teekib: Which layout is opening twice? The popup over a `ListView` item?

Comment: ..yes  popup over a ListView item

Comment: @teekib: So the problem is not the doAction() being called / run twice at all is it?

Comment: yes i think its not the doAction() in the menu item all others are clickable only  once ..this one menu item is getting clicked twice

Comment: @teekib: And where is the popup shown? Is it in the `Activity` that uses this adapter? That code might be the relevant one.

Comment: @teekib: Oh. Nice. Glad you found the solution. Don't forget to update the OP with what did the trick. It may help other users in the future. :-)

Comment: @teekib I glad you found the solution but you should change your understanding  and expectation from stackoverflow.com and your question is not clear about what you want to do.

Comment: I do agree with @ibrahimyilmaz. But there are times when you really aren't sure with what is wrong and causing a problem.